# Sort words alphabetically using dynamic arrays

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I came across a question in **C Programming: A Modern Approach** which goes as follows.[image]

**I am using `qsort` from `stdlib.h` and this is what I have so far:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

int read_line(char str[], int n);
static int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);
int main()
{

  char *words[MAX_LEN];
  int i = 0, j;
  char word_str[MAX_LEN + 1], s[20];

  for (;;)
    {
      printf("\nEnter a word:  ");
      fgets(s, 20, stdin);
      if (strcmp(s, "\n") == 0)
          break;
      read_line(word_str, MAX_LEN);
    }

  int len = strlen(word_str);
  words[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  strcpy(words[i], word_str);

  qsort(words, len, sizeof(char *), cmp);

  printf("\nIn sorted order:  ");
  for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
    printf("%s ", words[j]);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}

int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
  int ch, i = 0;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    if (i < n)
      str[i++] = ch;
  str[i] = '\0';
  return i;

}

static int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{

  return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);

}
```

**The output I receive:**
[image]

I am stuck at this point as my compiler does not give me an error and on debugging I see my `word_str` is empty.

I am new to **c** so please go easy.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wextra` to make gcc super picky, see if anything comes up.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 sortwords.c -o sortwords` still gives me no compilation errors.

Comment: ooh, you have a *real problem*. I'll reboot to Ubuntu and take a look.

Comment: `int len = strlen(word_str);
  words[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  strcpy(words[i], word_str);` move into for-loop and `++i`.

Comment: `qsort(words, len, sizeof(char *), cmp);` --> `qsort(words, i, sizeof(char *), cmp);`

Comment: `if (i < n)
      str[i++] = ch;` --> `if (i < n - 1)
      str[i++] = ch;`

Comment: Minor problem: the program waits for a newline before asking for a word again. [log](http://pastebin.com/wupxJu94)

Comment: @Blacksilver I have noticed that and it is because of my `fgets` usage to check for an empty input. I have tried using `while (scanf("%s", &s) != '\n'` but I keep getting `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why am I changing `if (i < n) str[i++] = ch;` --> `if (i < n - 1) str[i++] = ch;`I would really like to know what difference the two have. Thank you.

Comment: for `str[i] = '\0';` (Even if it is `char word_str[MAX_LEN + 1]..read_line(word_str, MAX_LEN);`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That makes sense, I thought I had to account the `delimiter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code.

**Problem 1**

The code to save the lines of text in `words` needs to be inside the `for` loop.

```
for (;;)
{
  printf("\nEnter a word:  ");
  fgets(s, 20, stdin);
  if (strcmp(s, "\n") == 0)
      break;
  read_line(word_str, MAX_LEN);

  int len = strlen(word_str);
  words[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  strcpy(words[i], word_str);
}
```

**Problem 2**

You don't have a counter to keep track of the number of lines read.

Use:

```
int num_lines = 0;
for (;; ++num_lines)
{
  printf("\nEnter a word:  ");
  fgets(s, 20, stdin);
  if (strcmp(s, "\n") == 0)
      break;
  read_line(word_str, MAX_LEN);

  int len = strlen(word_str);
  words[num_lines] = malloc(len + 1);
  strcpy(words[num_lines], word_str);
}
```

**Problem 3**

You are passing the wrong value in the second argument to `qsort`. You need to pass `num_lines`, not the length of the last string.

```
qsort(words, num_lines, sizeof(char *), cmp);
```

**Problem 4**

Don't use `len` in the conditional of the for loop when printing the sorted strings. Use `num_lines` instead.

```
for (j = 0; j < num_lines; j++)
  printf("%s ", words[j]);
```

Comment: Even after changing `len` in the conditional `for loop` with `num_lines` my program still prints an empty array at `In sorted order:`

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib, I think there is some logic error in reading the data from `stdin`. I haven't been able to identify it yet.

Comment: Is it because I am using `fgets` to do my `exit check`? I was reading the textbook and it said I could use `scanf` too, but everytime I use `while (scanf("%s", &s) != '\n'` I get `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`